# Editing variable-length collections with complex object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to implement an Editor in ASP.NET MVC application for a Model with ICollection property in it.

```
public class Peson 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<PersonCode> {get; set;}
}

public class PersonCode 
{
   public int PersonId {get; set;}
   public int Code {get; set;}
   public int SubCode {get; set;}
}
```

In PersonCode class each SubCode depends on Code for example for Code 1 we can choose only SubCodes 2,3 and for Code 2 SubCodes 5,7

Each Code and SubCode has a description stored somewhere in database

So I need to edit this collection (add,delete,edit items in it) inside my Person object on a single Person Edit page and also provide dropdown lists for choosing Code and SubCode.

Comment: i've tried to reproduce http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/ . The only problem is if Model is not valid and it returns to view i need to supply two SubCode dropdownlist with options but I do not know how.

Comment: You have not given enough information to explain what you really need to do. Are there a fixed number of `PersonCode` for a person? Do you need to add them dynamically while editing `Person`? As far as selecting a `Code` then associated `SubCode`'s you will need to create cascading dropdown lists where you make an ajax call to populate the SubCodes based on the selected Code. Show your view so that we can understand what your trying to do.